# jQuery alternative to scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, scrolltop

I need to detect how far from top the document has been scrolled and for that I used `scrollTop()`. Unfortunatelly it doesn't work on some versions of Android and therefor I need a different solution. Is there a way I could get the `$(document).scrollTop` without `scrollTop` function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me, hope it works for you too

```
 var body = document.body;
 var docElem = document.documentElement;
 var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `window.pageYOffset` to determine the offset from the top. E.G:

```
alert(window.pageXOffset + window.pageYOffset);
```